# Furnace + boiler in a closet with top open to the attic

Tags: insulation, central-heating

I have a furnace and boiler (both gas) in one closet whose floor has a vent at the bottom and the top is completely open to the attic. The attic has blown in cellulose insulation and it falls in this closet when there is work done there.
Is this normal or can I partly cover the top with drywall leaving some opening? Any advise on this is highly appreciated.
1600 sq ft house
The boiler and furnace exhaust are channeled into the chimney.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure they can get enough makeup air for combustion, so that they don't backdraft, but yes, you can and should cover the top, that is absolutely awful for any sort of energy efficiency.